# How can I persist a file in android 11?

Tags: android, save, android-11, android-storage, scoped-storage

I want to persist a file even after uninstalling my app in android 11 . Thanks to android 10 and 11 update about the storage I'm not able to do that any more . Also I don't want to use Data backup or a remote server .It has to be offline. any suggestion ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the file in the normal way in the Documents folder.

After reinstallation use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user choose the file.

For an Android Q/10 device request legacy external storage in manifest file and you can continue as before 10.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to user know about it .